# Nuxt.js: Conditional client/server side rendering

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

The goal:

Use vue.js to serve a website with many routes and dynamic content which has open graph and twitter rich cards meta data markup.

The idea:

Requests with `user agent` containing Twitterbot, facebookexternalhit and so on get redirected to a Server Side Rendering website. All the other users get Client Side Rendering version.

The question:

Is it possible in Nuxt.js to make this conditional rendering? If yes, how? If not, any solutions to the above problem?

[Credits to the idea](https://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app/)

Comment: @jacob That's not correct because I have infinite amount of routes. Secondly the data change often. So prerendering is not an option

Comment: nuxt doesnt bring it per default, so you would need to write at least some basic server scripts. express for example. this is also achievable without nuxt, after using `build` and serving it with another application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt can conditionally render a single page (CSR) or not (SSR) after the client request was received:

```
module.exports = {
 path: '/public',
 handler(req, res, next) {

   res.spa = req.headers['user-agent'] !== 'Twitterbot' 
   next()
 }
}
```